# How to compare which interest rate is better compounded annual vs compounded 3 times a year

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having a little trouble with getting the answer to this question.

: How much better is the return on a 4% yearly interest rate investment that is compounded 3 times per year as opposed to compounded yearly?

I tried to set up the equation as :

10000(1.04)^n = 10000(1+.04/3)^3n    n=1

then to compare the them :

10400/ 1040535704 = 0.999485

I'm guessing I am not setting things up right...

I am suppose to get answer 1% - 1.5% better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right thing in comparing $1.04$ to $\left(1+\frac {0.04}3\right)^3$.  You don't want to write it as an equation because they are not equal.  The difference is $\left(1+\frac {0.04}3\right)^3-1.04\approx0.0005357$ as you found.  The percentage difference you are supposed to find is the increased percentage of interest
$$\frac {0.0405357}{0.04} \approx 1.0134$$ which is an increase of $1.34\%$ in the interest received, not an increase of that much in the effective interest rate.  Anybody using percentages should make clear what the number is that percentage of.  I think it is better to state that you are getting an increase of $0.05357\%$ in the effective interest rate.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense. 
I just joined math stackexchange, I look forward to being a part of the community.